# OpenCV camera capture no light

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to take a picture using the webcam on my Mac. I am using OpenCV to do so. However, if the lights are off in the room, the picture is extremely dark. Is there any way to use 'flash' to get light into the image? Or are there any other alternatives to get light into the image?

If you have any questions or need more information, feel free to ask.

Here is my code to take a picture:

```
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
input('Press Enter to capture')
return_value, image = camera.read()
cv2.imwrite('opencv'+'.png', image)
del(camera)
```

Comment: By using flash, you mean something like put your screen completely white during the capture ?

Comment: Yes, something like that to make sure the picture isn't dark if the lights are off in the room. @thibsc

Answer (score 1):

You can display a white image on the screen to make a "flash":

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

flash_lite = np.ones((1080,1920), np.uint8) * 255

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
input('Press Enter to capture')

cv2.namedWindow ('flash', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.setWindowProperty ('flash', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.imshow ('flash', flash_lite)
cv2.waitKey(100)

return_value, image = camera.read()
cv2.destroyWindow('flash')

cv2.imwrite('opencv.png', image)
```

Comment: This is helpful but I can't have any other screen popup as the program is intended to detect if my eyes are closed automatically whilst I'm doing a task.

Comment: You want a flash but is a problem ? Explain exactly what you want to achieve, it's hard to help without this. I don't see the problem, if you take the picture during this flash and close when it's done

Comment: If you would like reference, when you take a picture on Mac's PhotoBooth, the screen flashes just before the picture is taken, is there a feature like that? I just need to bring light into the picture @thibsc

Comment: @Akkfic, I updated my answer to give you a complete example. I try and it works for me even if the flash is not so powerful, but it gives a light on the picture

Answer (score 0):

Since you always turning on your screen. You can increase the camera bightness

```
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, brightness)
```

You can get the current brightness from the camera using this

```
brightness = cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS.get(10)
```

Then try play with the brightness

Please take note that this will affect your image processing.Its better get a USB light source for this.

For more control you can refer to [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html)

I dont have MAc maybe you can consider [this](https://osxdaily.com/2019/08/14/change-screen-brightness-mac-terminal/) if works create script call from your python

Comment: I will try this now. Is the second parenthesis at the end a type? @WenJuan

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. The picture is still dark when taken in a dark room. @WenJuan

Comment: you can try increase the CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE  but i still think that you need a light source for your application

Comment: https://osxdaily.com/2019/08/14/change-screen-brightness-mac-terminal/